# встроить ленту новостей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Я создаю ресурс и на его основе делаю ленту новостей. Затем вывожу её в шаблон `index.html.erb`. Код контроллера:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @news = News.all
  end
end
```

вот код шаблона:

```
<% @news.each do |news_item| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to(news_path(news_item.id)) do %>
        <div><%= news_item.title %></div>
        <div><%= truncate(news_item.text, length: 100) %></div>
        <hr />
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Теперь я хотел бы выводить эту ленту новостей не на одной странице, но на всех (в боковой колонке). Для этого мне нужно сделать запрос в БД из `applicationController` примерно следующим образом:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_news_list
    @get_news_list = News.all
  end  
end
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как `@get_news_list` передать в каждый шаблоню

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать просто `<%= render 'news/index.html.erb' %>`?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_news_list
    @get_news_list = News.all
  end
  before_action :get_news_list
end
```